# Why User defined Exception not throws over Generic Exception?

Tags: java, exception

I have created below User Defined Exception (`MyException`) class which extends `Exception`, Now I manually try to create a `NullPointerException`, But instead of throwing (`MyException`), it throws the same Generic(`NullPointerException`) Exception

```
public class Sample {
   public static void main(String[] args) throws MyException {
       String a = null;

       callMethod(a);
   }

   public static void callMethod(String a) throws MyException {
       a.toString();
   }
}
```

```
public class MyException extends Exception {
    public MyException(String exception)
    {
        super(exception);
    }
}
```

Below is the Exception I'm getting

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Sample.callMethod(Sample.java:9)
    at Sample.main(Sample.java:5)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Because accessing a method on `null` throws a NullPointerException.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fact that you declare that a method throws an exception does not mean it will throw that exception when any other exception is thrown in the code.

In this case, `a` is `null` so the exception that's thrown is a `NullPointerException`. If you wanted to throw your custom exception you would have to check whether your value is null and throw your custom exception, like this

```
public static void callMethod(String a) throws MyException {
    if (a == null) {
        throw new MyException(e);
    }
    a.toString();
}
```

Comment: Simply using throws, is being useless in this case? then is that mean that i should wrap my login inside try catch block always?

Comment: I would _strongly_ suggest doing `if (a == null) throw new MyException();` rather than this to avoid double-filling the stack trace.  I'd also consider a slight rewording of the first part to highlight that just declaring an exception doesn't actually cause it to be thrown, you need to actually throw it.  (I know your example shows this, but it seems the OP is confused on this fact.)

Comment: @user2478398 you're right. I'm fixing the `try...catch`

Comment: @RenceAbi I think you may be a bit confused about how exceptions work. In principle, even the ones that you encounter in the standard library are thrown by some piece of code with a `throw`. It's your code that decides whether throwing an exception is warranted, they don't just pop up because you say a method may throw them. You have to tell them in what case to throw them, which is achieved by throwing an exception when certain conditions are met.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Yes, that looks better to me.  Upped.

Answer (score 1):

Declaring that a method `throws MyException` means that it *may* throw that exception.

It does **not** mean that all thrown exceptions automatically get wrapped in your MyException

Comment: If i want to throw MyException in that case, should i always wrap my code inside try block?

Comment: since it is a checked exception, you should wrap the invocation in try-catch, or rethrow the exception higher somehow.

Comment: That, or check for null beforehand and throw your exception

Answer (score 0):

Using throws MyException does mean that the method can throw an exception and u need to handle it, but it doesn't mean every exception u get inside the method will be thrown as MyException. If u want to throw every Exception u get as MyException you can do :

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws MyException {
   try{
       String a = null;

       callMethod(a);
   }catch(Exception e){
      throw new MyException(...);
   }
}
```

Comment: Please, don't suggest catching `Exception`. It's bad design. I see what you're trying to do, and in this instance it's probably not dangerous, but in general it's a good way to write impossible to debug code.